# Why this C++ program is not printing anything?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, vector, data-structures

> I have this C++ program but its not printing anything in the console.
> I am copying the content of the string in 2 vectors and doing count increment operations on them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s;
  cin>>s;
  int i,j;
  vector<char> a;
  vector<char> b;
  int count1=0;
  int count2=0;
  int count3=0;
  int t=s.length()/2;
  for(i=0;i<t-1;t++)
  {
      a.push_back(s[i]);
  }
  for(j=t;j<s.length();j++)
  {
      b.push_back(s[j]);
  }
        int e1,e2;
  for (auto it1 = a.begin(), it2 = b.begin();
     it1 != a.end() && it2 != b.end(); 
     ++it1, ++it2)
  {
      if(int(*it1)>int(*it2))
         count1++;
 
      if(int(*it1)<int(*it2))
         count2++;
 
      if(int(*it1)==int(*it2))
         count3++;
  }
  
  cout<<min(min(count1,count2),count3);
}
```

> I am printing the minimum of the three counts in the end.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program? Also, `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is bad practice.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: You are allowed to (at least temporarily) cout intermediate results.  Example:    
out << "\n  count1: " << count1
      <<   "  count2: " << count2
      <<   "  count3: " << count3 << endl
      << "\n     min: " << min(min(count1,count2), count3) << endl;

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (you are pretty close).   What is missing is an example of input and expected output and actual output.

Comment: Several places you try to compare integers of different sign.  You should get in the habit of enabling more compiler warnings, such as.  [ warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ ....} [-Wsign-compare] ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your code fall into a infinite loop in the following.

```
for (i = 0; i < t - 1; t++)   // not t++, but it should be i++
{
    a.push_back(s[i]);
}
```

I also believe that a debugging skill helps you finding a bug in your program.

Answer (score 0):

After your insert `cin>>s;` the program keep waiting a data inserted, after the data inserted on variable `string s`but after this your code it does not seem clear about its objectives, because, for several inputs, your method with the internal if's will basically accomplish nothing, what is your original objective?

In your for have a loops.
Overwrite your original block quote to:

```cpp
  int t=s.length()/2;
  for(i=0;i<t-1;i++)
  {
      a.push_back(s[i]);
  }
```

Comment: after i press enter after inputting the string,it must execute right?

Comment: Yes, and i now believe this overwrite to code is enough to print correct objetive your, when i inserted "aafdsfsadfsdfasdfsdfs" the output is "3", it seems correct for dfs

Comment: yes,it was just a silly mistake.sorry for troubling you guys.